# Error during Visual Studio Publishing using Webdeploy

Tags: visual-studio-2013, webdeploy

I am trying to web deploy from visual studio using the publishing wizard.
I am getting the following error:

```
Error 101  Specified condition "$(AspNetMerge)" evaluates to "" instead of a boolean.
```

Am I missing some configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with AspNetMerge but it looks like its used to combine ASP.NET assemblies.  Regardless it looks like the AspNetMerge MSBuild property has not been defined.  You can try adding the following to the bottom of your project file (.csproj) file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AspNetMerge>true</AspNetMerge>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Obviously you should set the value to true or false depending on if you want to merge or not.